# Possible to generlize XP sysprep?

Tags: windows, image

Is is possible to generalize sysprep an xp image, similar to how win 7 does when you check the generalize box.

Meaning that, if I load the correct drivers for another model before syspreping, I would be able to use that image on another model computer than what it was orginally syspreped on. The 2 models would not be simial either.

I know that it wouldn't be the exact same thing if it is even possible.

If you need more info please let me know.

Thank You all for your help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply David. I should have put this in the op but I knew that sysprep for XP and newer was not designed for doing what I was asking.

Comment: I was wondering if adding the driver files to %systemroot%\system32 and %systemroot%\inf would accomplish what I was asking or if that still wouldn't work.

Comment: No, it won't. [In this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc765993(v=ws.10).aspx) you will find this comment "Sysprep for Windows Vista is independent of the Hardware Abstraction Layer (HAL). You can create a generalized x86 Windows image and transfer that image to any x86-based operating system.". This change was introduced in Vista to solve issues exactly like you are asking about. The only way to image XP for different hardware is to create a new image for each model, and maintain them separately.

Comment: "...XP and *newer was not..." *older. Sorry, typo.

Comment: Thanks for the answers David and WinOutreach4. I know that "almost" anything is possible so I thought I'd throw that question out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. Windows XP was not designed for disk duplication on different hardware. [This article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457073.aspx) shows that you can only use disk duplication on similar hardware, and [this page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457067.aspx) shows the exact needs for it to work properly.

(for disclosure)

David

Windows Outreach Team - IT Pro

[The Springboard Series on TechNet](http://www.microsoft.com/springboard)